# Separation of variables in partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I have a differential equation which possibly depends on all independent variables of the problem

```
{ϕ[t], Subscript[x, cm2][t], Subscript[z, cm2][t], 
 Subscript[θ, 1][t], Subscript[ϕ, 1][t], Subscript[ψ, 1][t]}
```

And it has a solution

```
S[ϕ[t],Subscript[x, cm2][t] ,Subscript[z, cm2][t],
  Subscript[θ, 1][t],Subscript[ϕ, 1][t],Subscript[ψ, 1][t]]
```

Which is of this form

```
W1[ϕ[t]] + W2[Subscript[x, cm2][t]] + W3[Subscript[z, cm2][t]] +
W4[Subscript[θ, 1][t]] + W5[Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]] + W6[Subscript[ψ, 1][t]]
```

And I want to get each of these 6 functions for which I write

```
DSolve[hamiltonjacobiequation == 0, {W1[ϕ[t]], 
W2[Subscript[x, cm2][t]], W3[Subscript[z, cm2][t]], 
W4[Subscript[θ, 1][t]], W5[Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]], 
W6[Subscript[ψ, 1][t]]}, {ϕ[t], Subscript[x, cm2][t] , 
Subscript[z, cm2][t], Subscript[θ, 1][t], 
Subscript[ϕ, 1][t], Subscript[ψ, 1][t]}]
```

And it gives me error

> DSolve::alliv: The function W1[ϕ[t]] was specified without dependence on all the independent variables. Each function must depend on all the independent variables.

How do I get all 6 of these functions?

With:

```
hamiltonjacobiequation=T + (1/(2*i*m*Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
           (d^2*M*Subscript[R, o]^2 + m*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2*
                  Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2)^2))*
     (d^2*i*m*M*Subscript[R, o]^6*(-2*d^2*g*m*M*Sin[    θ] + 

       2*Cot[θ]*Csc[θ]*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*
        Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]]*
               Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]] + 
       Cot[θ]*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*
               (Cot[θ]*
           Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2] - 
                  2*Subscript[z, cm2][t])*
        Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]]^2 + 

       2*Cot[θ]*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*Subscript[x, cm2][t]*
        Derivative[1][W2][
                 Subscript[x, cm2][t]]*
        Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][t]]) + 
        Subscript[R, 
       o]^4*(2*i*m*Cot[θ]*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^3*
               ((-d^2)*M*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2 + 
          m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2)*
               Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]]*
        Derivative[1][W3][
                 Subscript[z, cm2][t]] + 
       2*d^2*i*m*M*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*
               Subscript[x, cm2][t]*
        Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^
                     2]*(Csc[θ]*Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]] - 
          Subscript[z, cm2][t]*
                    Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]])*
        Derivative[1][W3][
                 Subscript[z, cm2][t]] + i*m*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2*
               (Cot[θ]*
           Csc[θ]*(-2*d^2*M*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2 + 
                       2*m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2)*
           Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]]*
                    Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]] + 

          Cot[θ]*((-d^2)*M*Cot[θ]*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*
              Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - 
                             Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2] + 
             4*d^2*M*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*
                         Subscript[z, cm2][t] + 
             m*Cot[θ]*Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - 
                             Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
              Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2 - 
                       2*m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^3)*
           Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][
                          t]]^2 + 
          d^2*M*(2*g*m*Sin[θ]*(d^2*M - 2*m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^
                                2) + 
             Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - 
                             Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
              Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][
                               t]]^2)) + 
       d^2*M*Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - 

          Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*(i*m*Csc[θ]^2*
           Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*
                    Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]]^2 - 
          2*i*m*Csc[θ]*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*
                    Subscript[z, cm2][t]*
           Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]]*
                    Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]] + 

          i*(d^2*M + m*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2)*
                    Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]]^2 + 
                  d^2*M*(i*Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][t]]^2 + 

             m*(-2*d*g*i*M*Cos[θ] - 
                d^2*i*M*Sin[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2 - 

                2*g*i*m*Cos[θ]*Subscript[z, cm2][t] + 

                Derivative[1][W4][Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2 + 

                Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                 Derivative[1][W5][Subscript[ϕ, 1][
                                    t]]^2 - 
                2*Cot[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]*
                 Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]*

                 Derivative[1][W5][Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]]*
                 Derivative[1][W6][
                                Subscript[ψ, 1][t]] - 
                Cot[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                              Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                 Derivative[1][W6][Subscript[ψ, 1][
                                    t]]^2 + 
                Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^4*

                 Derivative[1][W6][Subscript[ψ, 1][t]]^2)))) + 
        m*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^4*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2*
          (i*(-2*m*Cot[θ]*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2*
           Subscript[z, cm2][t] + 
                  Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
                    (d^2*M*(-2 + Sin[ϕ[t]]^2) - 
             m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2))*
               Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]]^2 + 
             2*i*m*Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
               Subscript[z, cm2][t]*
        Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]]*
               (Csc[θ]*Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]] + 
          Subscript[x, cm2][t]*
                    Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][t]]) + 

       m*Subscript[z, cm2][
          t]^2*(2*g*i*m^2*Sin[θ]*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2 + 
                  Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
                    (i*Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][t]]^2 + 

             m*(-2*d*g*i*M*Cos[θ] - 
                d^2*i*M*Sin[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2 - 

                2*g*i*m*Cos[θ]*Subscript[z, cm2][t] + 

                Derivative[1][W4][Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2 + 

                Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                 Derivative[1][W5][Subscript[ϕ, 1][
                                    t]]^2 - 
                2*Cot[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]*
                 Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]*

                 Derivative[1][W5][Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]]*
                 Derivative[1][W6][
                                Subscript[ψ, 1][t]] - 
                Cot[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                              Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                 Derivative[1][W6][Subscript[ψ, 1][
                                    t]]^2 + 
                Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^4*

                 Derivative[1][W6][Subscript[ψ, 1][t]]^2)))) + 
        Subscript[R, o]^2*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2*
          ((-i)*(m*Cot[θ]*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2*
           Subscript[z, cm2][t]*
                    (2*d^2*M*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2 + 
             m*Cot[θ]*Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - 
                             Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
              Subscript[z, cm2][t] - 
                       4*m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2) + 
                  Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
                    (d^4*M^2 - 
             2*d^2*m*M*Cos[ϕ[t]]^2*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2 - 
                       m^2*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^4))*
               Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]]^2 - 
       i*m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]*
               (2*m*Cot[θ]*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2*
           Subscript[z, cm2][t] + 
                  2*Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
                    ((-d^2)*M*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2 + 
             m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2))*
               Derivative[1][W2][Subscript[x, cm2][t]]*
               (Csc[θ]*Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]] + 
          Subscript[x, cm2][t]*
                    Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][t]]) + 

       m*Subscript[z, cm2][
          t]^2*(2*i*m*Csc[θ]*Subscript[x, cm2][t]*
                    Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
                    Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]]*
           Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][t]] + 

          i*m*Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2*(2*g*m*Sin[θ]*(2*d^2*M - 
                            m*Subscript[z, cm2][t]^2) + 
             Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - 
                             Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
              Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][
                               t]]^2) + 
          Sqrt[Subscript[R, o]^2 - Subscript[x, cm2][t]^2]*
                    (i*m*Csc[θ]^2*
              Derivative[1][W1][ϕ[t]]^2 + 

             2*d^2*M*(i*Derivative[1][W3][Subscript[z, cm2][t]]^2 + 


                m*(-2*d*g*i*M*Cos[θ] - 
                   d^2*i*M*Sin[θ]^2*Sin[ϕ[t]]^2 - 

                   2*g*i*m*Cos[θ]*Subscript[z, cm2][t] + 
                   Derivative[1][W4][
                                    Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2 + 
                   Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*

                    Derivative[1][W5][Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]]^2 - 

                   2*Cot[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]*
                    Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]*

                    Derivative[1][W5][Subscript[ϕ, 1][t]]*
                    Derivative[1][W6][
                                    Subscript[ψ, 1][t]] - 
                   Cot[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                                   Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^2*
                    Derivative[1][W6][
                                     Subscript[ψ, 1][t]]^2 + 
                   Csc[Subscript[θ, 1][t]]^4*

                    Derivative[1][W6][Subscript[ψ, 1][t]]^2))))))
```

Comment: What's the definition of `hamiltonjacobiequation`?

Comment: I posted it as an answer , as you can see it is not very nice looking function

Comment: You should add that to your question by clicking the "edit" button at the left bottom corner of your question rather than post it as an answer. Also, to make the code a bit nicer looking, you can press `Ctrl+Shift+I` in your notebook to convert it to `InputForm` before pasting it here.

Comment: Subscript is not your friend. Anyway, I think the error message is pretty clear. Each function must depend on all the independent variables.